# How to extract a fragment of text from file?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with the following text:

```
<div>
<b>a:</b> <a class='a' href='/a/1'>a1</a><br>
<b>b:</b> <a class='b' href='/b/2'>b2</a><br>
<b>c:</b> <a class='c' href='/c/3/'>c3</a><br>
<b>d:</b> "ef"<br><br><div class='start'>123
<br>ghij.
<br>klmn
<br><br><b>end</b>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to do the following:

1. Whenever a line starts with `<b>a:</b> <a class='a'`, I want to copy the text between the `>` symbol after `<a class='a'` and `</a>` — it must be stored in `a[1]`;
2. Similarly, whenever a line starts with `<b>b:</b> <a class='b'`, I want to copy the text between the `>` symbol after `<a class='b'` and `</a>` — it must be stored in `b[1]`;
3. Whenever a line contains `<div class='start'>`, I want to create the variable `t` whose value starts with the text that occurs between `<div class='start'>` and the end of this line, then set `flag` to `1`;
4. If the value of `flag` is already `1` and the current line does not start with `<br><br><b>end</b>`, I want to append the current line to the current value of the variable `t` (using the space symbol as separator);
5. If the value of `flag` is already `1` and the current line starts with `<br><br><b>end</b>`, I want to concatenate three current values of `a[1]`, `b[1]` and `t` (using `;` as separator) and print the result to the output file, then set `flag` to `0`, then clear the variable `t`.

I used the following code (for `gawk 4.0.1`):

```
gawk 'BEGIN {flag = 0; t = ""; } 
{  
if ($0 ~ /^<b>a:<\/b> <a class=\x27a\x27/ ) {
    match($0, /^<b>a:<\/b> <a class=\x27a\x27 href=\x27\/a\/[0-9]{1,}\x27>(.*)<\/a>/, a) };
if ($0 ~ /^<b>b:<\/b> <a class=\x27b\x27/ ) {
    match($0, /^<b>b:<\/b> <a class=\x27b\x27 href=\x27\/b\/[0-9]{1,}\x27>(.*)<\/a>/, b) };
if ($0 ~ /<div class=\x27start\x27>/ ) {
    match($0, /^.*<div class=\x27start\x27>(.*)$/, s);
    t = s[1];
    flag = 1 };
if (flag == 1) {
    if ($0 ~ /^<br><br><b>end<\/b>/) {
        str = a[1] ";" b[1] ";" t;
        print(str) > "output.txt";
        flag = 0; str = ""; t = "" } 
    else {
    t = t " " $0 }
}
}' input.txt
```

I was expecting the following output:

```
a1;b2;123 <br>ghij. <br>klmn
```

But the output is:

```
;;123 <b>d:</b> "ef"<br><br><div class='start'>123 <br>ghij. <br>klmn
```

Why are `a[1]` and `b[1]` empty? Why does `<b>d:</b> "ef"<br><br><div class='start'>` occur in the output? How to fix the code to obtain the expected output?

Comment: awk does not do the perl-ish `.*?` non-greedy regex. You'd be better off with perl.

Comment: @glennjackman: it is not just `awk`, it is `gawk 4.0.1`, so it must be able to store the captured regex. I have done it before. And `123` after two semicolons means that gawk stored the captured regex.

Comment: Yes gawk's `match` can capture the parenthesized pieces. That does not mean that gawk's regular expression syntax includes `.*?` -- [it does not](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answers to your specific questions:

1. Q) Why are `a[1]` and `b[1]` empty?

   A) They aren't when I try your script with gawk 5.1.1 so most likely either there's a bug in your awk version or some of the white space in your input isn't blanks as your script requires (maybe it's tabs), or you have some control chars or your awk version doesn't like using `\x27` instead of `\047` for `'`s.
2. Q) Why does `<b>d:</b> "ef"<br><br><div class='start'>` occur in the output?

   A) Because you forgot a `next` in  the block that matches on `div` so the next block is also executing and saving `$0` from the `div` line.
3. Q) How to fix the code to obtain the expected output?

   A) Here's how I'd approach your problem, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\s` shorthand for `[:space:]`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gawk '
    BEGIN { OFS=";" }

    match($0, /^<b>(.):<\/b>\s+<a\s+class=\047.\047\s+href=\047\/.\/[0-9]+\/?\047>(.*)<\/a>/, arr) {
        vals[arr[1]] = arr[2]
    }

    match($0, /^.*<div\s+class=\047start\047>(.*)/, arr) {
        vals["div"] = arr[1]
        inDiv = 1
        next
    }

    inDiv {
        if ( /^<br><br><b>end<\/b>/ ) {
            print vals["a"], vals["b"], vals["div"]
            delete vals
            inDiv = 0
        }
        else {
            vals["div"] = vals["div"] " " $0
        }
    }

' 'input.txt' > 'output.txt'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ cat output.txt
a1;b2;123 <br>ghij. <br>klmn
```

So

1. I'm using a single `match()` to capture all values for lines that look like your a, b, c lines for consistency, conciseness, and maintainability.
2. I'm always saving the match results in an array named `arr` rather  than different arrays per occurrence so I don't have to remember to keep deleting those arrays and the code that uses the matches can all be homogenized.
3. I'm using a single associative array `vals[]` to hold all values indexed by the letter after `<b>` so we don't need to test those letters and create separate variables, it's easy to clear the data by just deleting the array rather than having to set multiple variables to null, and it's easy to add the `c` or any other similar values to the output later if desired.
4. I'm using `\s+` instead of a single blank char for every space in the input to be agnostic about the actual space char(s) and number of spaces used.
5. I'm using `\047` instead of `\x27` to match `'`s for portability and robustness, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.
6. I'm letting the shell handle all input/output rather than including output redirection in the awk script for consistency and improved robustness in error scenarios like files that can't be opened.
7. I named my flag variable `inDiv` rather than `flag` so it tells us what it means, i.e. that we're in the `div` block of the input, for improved clarity and easy of future maintenance. Naming a flag variable `flag` is like naming a numeric variable `number` instead of `sum`, `count`, `ave`, `tot`, `diff` or something else meaningful that'd improve your script. When you see people use `f` for the name of a flag variable, that `f` is shorthand for `found`, not for `flag`.

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrating that gawk's regexes don't match perl's

perl:

```bash
$ echo aaaab | perl -nE '/a*(a+b)/ && say $1'
ab
$ echo aaaab | perl -nE '/a*?(a+b)/ && say $1'
aaaab
```

`a*?` matched the *shortest* sequence of zero or more a's, and the greedy `a+` consumed the rest.

gawk

```
$ echo aaaab | gawk 'match($0, /a*(a+b)/, m) {print m[1]}'
ab
$ echo aaaab | gawk 'match($0, /a*?(a+b)/, m) {print m[1]}'
ab
```

Not the same behaviour: `a*?` is still greedy.

Comment: This is why the common advice is "parse XML with an XML parser" -- regular expressions just aren't the right tool.

Comment: I have edited the question. The code does not work with greedy regexes too.

Comment: Which is another demonstration of why you want to use a proper XML parser like `xmlstarlet` or etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Why(...)`a[1]`(...)empty?

[`match` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) does return `0` if not match was found, which allows to easy check if this is case, I selected part pertaining to filling a-array and altered it a bit

```
{
if ($0 ~ /^<b>a:<\/b> <a class=\x27a\x27/ )
{
print NR, match($0, /^<b>a:<\/b> <a class=\x27a\x27 href=\x27\/a\/[0-9]{1,}>(.*)<\/a>/, a);
}
}
```

then used it again

```
<div>
<b>a:</b> <a class='a' href='/a/1'>a1</a><br>
<b>b:</b> <a class='b' href='/b/2'>b2</a><br>
<b>c:</b> <a class='c' href='/c/3/'>c3</a><br>
<b>d:</b> "ef"<br><br><div class='start'>123
<br>ghij.
<br>klmn
<br><br><b>end</b>
</div>
</div>
```

and got output

```
2 0
```

so condition in `if` worked as expected as line with `<b>a:</b>`... is 2nd line, however match was not found. This mean your regular expression is wrong, after examining, your regular expression is missing one single quote, it should be

```
/^<b>a:<\/b> <a class=\x27a\x27 href=\x27\/a\/[0-9]{1,}\x27>(.*)<\/a>/
```

then

```
{
if ($0 ~ /^<b>a:<\/b> <a class=\x27a\x27/ )
{
print NR, match($0, /^<b>a:<\/b> <a class=\x27a\x27 href=\x27\/a\/[0-9]{1,}\x27>(.*)<\/a>/, a);
print a[1];
}
}
```

does give output

```
2 1
a1
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: I added those two quotes.. The code still does not work. The output is the same.